# can a aspx page have more than one aspx.cs class to inherit?

Tags: asp.net

i want to know, can one aspx page have two or more code behind page?
like if i have page collge.aspx, by default it will inherit college.aspx.cs, i want to know can't it inherit more then one aspx.cs. If not then why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class cannot inherit two different base classes.  (.Net does not support multiple inheritance)

However, you can inherit a single base class which is split among multiple files using the `partial` keyword.

Comment: can two different aspx page inherit the same aspx.cs class?

Comment: @Novice: Yes.  You can set the code-behind for each one to the same file & classname.  However, it probably wouldn't work well with event handlers.

Comment: You probably want to make a shared base class that inherits `Page`, then make the code-behind file for each of your pages inherit that class (`public class Default : MyBasePage`)

Comment: I had never though of this issue in such a simple way. Its just the single inheritance idiom of C#

Answer (score 3):

**No**
C# does not support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET you only have single inheritance, but multiple interface implementation.

> have two or more code behind page?

Well in .NET you have the principle of **partial classes** so you could create multiple files and spread the logic of that one class over these files. In ASP.NET the `.aspx.designer.cs` file does the same actually.